# Clearing stack memory allocated in main()?

Tags: c++

I've been calling heap pointers now for as long as I can remember, which in turn has caused me to think about their implications while writing and what I realised was I have no knowledge on how or even if it is possible to clear a stack variable declared within main() from memory once it has been allocated.

Clearly I can just use a struct and destructor or similar, which I would but lets for say I wanted to remove an array that was on the stack declared in main()  is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean by `calling heap pointers`?

Comment: Why do you feel the need to do this? Are you worried that by not "removing an array that was on the stack declared in main()" you'd have a memory leak? If so, why do you think this?

Comment: Why do you want to do this anyway?  If you want to destroy something on the stack, you need to let it go out of scope.

Comment: If someone was writing code for an embedded system that would be running for a very long time and used stack variables overlooking a destructor wouldnt it be a bad?

Comment: You *could* wrap it in a scope (`{}`). It'll be destroyed when the scope ends.

Comment: Destructors work on arrays, just like they work on structs (except of course the destructor will be called multiple times, once for each item in the array).

Comment: If you want control over when it's destroyed, don't create it on the stack. If it's created on the stack, it gets destroyed when the stack is destroyed.

Comment: Reminder:  Compiler may remove "stack" variables through optimization.  Also, the compiler may use registers instead of declaring variables on the stack.  Register memory area is usually different than stack space on most processors.

Comment: Keep in mind that the stack is... literally a stack. You can't simply pick and choose variables to free. You have to free whatever is above the variable on the stack as well. This is also true in assembly. So if you want assembly level control of the stack, you basically have it with a scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't really remove a variable out of the current, local scope.

It's not something you should be concerned with - the compiler takes care of everything there.

If you are concerned about privacy, you can of course blank the variable out after use.

Comment: Why are you saying that? Of course you can clear a local variable. You just need to create another local scope within your current scope, and declare your variable there. In fact, a lot of RAII idiom functionality hinges scope locality.

Answer (score 4):

> I wanted to remove an array that was on the stack declared in main()
>   is it possible?

Yes.

In main() (and most anywhere you use an automatic variable), you can trigger a dtor by closing the containing scope.

Example:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   int retVal = 0;
   int arr[10];
   T610_t  t610;
   retVal = t610.exec(argc, argv);
   // ...
   // ...  // t610 exists to end of main() scope.
   // ...  // arr[10] exists to end of main() scope
   return retVal;
}
```

Instance t610 (of the user defined T610_t type) lasts the life-time of the program, even when not used after the exec() returns retVal;

---

In contrast:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   int retVal = 0;
   {
      int arr[10];
      T610_t  t610;
      retVal = t610.exec(argc, argv);
   }
   // ...   // no t610 instance exists, and arr[] is no longer accessible
   // ...
   // ...
   // ...
   return retVal;
}
```

The dtor of instance t610 is called at the close-brace after exec() returns retVal.  arr[10] also no longer exists.

All the lines after the close brace do not have access to T610_t, nor arr[10], and any automatic memory grabbed in the 'small scope' is 'released' for re-use.  (for instance, another T610_t instance...)

Any 'clearing' of the space used by T610_t is dependent on what the dtor does and what you mean by clearing.  Thus, for instance, an array data attribute of T610_t can be filled with 0's (to 'clear' it), and the dtor also releases the memory for re-use.  Remember, do no delete when you did no 'new'.

Answer (score 2):

A semi-answer to demonstrate a trick the actual answers neglected. (Edit: Neglect changed by the time this was posted)

If you have a large block of memory that you allocated on the stack (an Automatic allocation) and you need that memory back without returning from the function, you can introduce a new scope by calling another function

```
int get_and_compute()
{ 
    int array[1024*1024];
    read_in_a_lot_of_inputs(array);
    return compute_stuff_with__array(array);
} 

int main()
{
    int result = get_and_compute();
    // now you have enough memory to call 
    job_that_takes_a_lot_of_RAM(result);
}
```

Or by surrounding the code in question with a set of braces

```
int main()
{
    int result = 0;
    { //introduce a new scope
        int array[1024*1024];
        read_in_a_lot_of_inputs(array);
        result = compute_stuff_with__array(array);
    } // array goes out of scope here
    // now you have enough memory to call 
    job_that_takes_a_lot_of_RAM(result);
}
```

Most of the time I prefer option 1, adding a function, but there are times where the extra function doesn't make much sense. Pick the option that is easiest to read, write, and maintain.

Answer (score 1):

> I wanted to remove an array that was on the stack declared in main() is it possible?

Simply let the execution go out of the scope where the automatic variable is declared:

```
int main() {
    {
        int arr[10];
    }
    // arr is destroyed, and further local variables can reuse its memory
}
```